# Deploy .Net Core 2.1 Web API to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get my .Net Core Web API Solution deployed to Elastic Beanstalk via CLI and I'm running into an issue. I am able to publish my project without errors and deploy the application successfully. My problem is that when I access the URL, I'm still seeing the Sample App.

Is there a config change that I can make to my app, or the web.config, or in Elastic Beanstalk that I should change to get my Web API deployed?

**publish command**

```
dotnet publish My.WebAPI/My.WebAPI.csproj --runtime win10-x64 --output my-api
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyWebAPI.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "deployments": {
        "aspNetCoreWeb": [
        {
            "name": "my-webapi",
            "parameters": {
                "appBundle": ".",
                "iisPath": "/",
                "iisWebSite": "Default Web Site"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @dyesdyes I answered below. I was a problem with our I was creating the zip  file for deployment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to fix the way I was zipping the publish content. My Jenkins deployment script is generating a custom zip. I was zipping the compiled code into a subdirectory, so my deployments were failing. I updated our zip command to flatten the archive, so all deployment files are in a flat file.

Per AWS Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html (Relevant passage below)

> When you use the AWS Elastic Beanstalk console to deploy a new application or an application version, you'll need to upload a source bundle. Your source bundle must meet the following requirements:
>
> - Consist of a single ZIP file or WAR file (you can include multiple WAR files inside your ZIP file)
> - Not exceed 512 MB
> - Not include a parent folder or top-level directory (subdirectories are fine)

Comment: Exactly. Managed to make it work to thanks to this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html
Feel free to add it to your answer.
Note that the hidden files are also important.